# SQL, get max id of column

Tags: sql-server, join, max

I've got this table in MS SQL Server Management Studio

```
+------+-----------+--------
| id   | client id | bla bla blaaaa
+------+-----------+--------
|    1 |   1       | .......
|    2 |   2       | .......
|    3 |   3       | .......
|    4 |   8       | .......
|    5 |   9       | .......
|    6 |   15      | .......
|    7 |   1       | .......
|    8 |   16      | .......
|    9 |   2       | .......
|   10 |   9       | .......
|   12 |   12      | .......
+------+-----------+--------
```

I need to get unique [client id] with max value of [id], like this

```
+------+-----------+--------
| id   | client id | bla bla blaaaa
+------+-----------+--------
|    3 |   3       | .......
|    4 |   8       | .......
|    6 |   15      | .......
|    7 |   1       | .......
|    8 |   16      | .......
|    9 |   2       | .......
|   10 |   9       | .......
|   12 |   12      | .......
+------+-----------+--------
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work well .. can someone help me?

```
SELECT *
FROM   table AS one 
INNER JOIN table AS two
   ON one.[client id] = two.[client id]
   WHERE one.[id] > two.[id]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT max(id), client_id, blah_blah
FROM my_table
GROUP BY client_id, blah_blah
```

Comment: i like the bla,_blah :D

Comment: Incorrect.  This answer treats client_id and blah_blah identically.  The goal was GROUP BY client_id.  Notice that duplicate client_id are removed in the example.  The goal is not to also remove duplicate blah_blah.  The above answer will return a row including the max(id) for each unique  client_id and blah_blah pair.   The question is about MS SQL's T-SQL.  If you were using MySQL instead you could do:  SELECT max(id), client_id, blah_blah
FROM my_table
GROUP BY client_id

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for `ROW_NUMBER()` solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [client id] ORDER BY [id] DESC) AS RN, *
    FROM table AS one
    ) AS T
WHERE T.RN = 1;
```